Is it possible to use an observable without subscribing?
Consulting articles and documentation, I saw that it is not possible to use an observable without subscribe, I have the following code in my service, why am I able to use the observable without subscribe? Wasn't it supposed to give an error?
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../models/user';

const httpOptions = {


  headers: new HttpHeaders({'content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

 BASE_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000/';


 constructor(private segurancaHttp: HttpClient) { }


 getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{ 
   return this.segurancaHttp.get<User[]>(this.BASE_URL + 'users')
}

addUser(user:any): Observable<User>{
  return this.segurancaHttp.post<User>(this.BASE_URL + 'users', user, httpOptions)
}

I'm studying observables and this is giving me a lot of doubts.

please add clarity to the question on how you are using the observable, using it means, subscribing to get the data, you have not shared the code that uses the observable,

But in this case, what can you say I'm doing? in this code specifically @Naren Murali

In this case, am I not using the observable? Is that what you meant? I'm a little lost, sorry @Naren Murali

you are configuring the httpClient method with the necessary parameters for GET PUT POST, so that when you call the method, you get an observable, that is ready to fetch you the data once you subscribe to it. The code you shared is the setting up of the HTTP client for making API call with proper parameters, that will fetch you the desired data

it is like getting a car ready (observable), it should have petrol, mirrors adjusted, seatbelt on (url, body, queryParams, http headers), the car is ready to go (but in neutral), but unless you operate the pedals and gear shift the car won't move (subscribing)

You are configuring the httpClient method with the necessary parameters for GET PUT POST, so that when you call the method, you get an observable, that is ready to fetch you the data once you subscribe to it. The code you shared is the setting up of the HTTP client for making API call with proper parameters, that will fetch you the desired data.
Analogy: it is like getting a car ready (observable), it should have petrol, mirrors adjusted, seatbelt on (url, body, queryParams, http headers), the car is ready to go (but in neutral), but unless you operate the pedals and gear shift the car won't move (subscribing)
To actually use the observable, you should call it on your component by importing the service.
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  userService = inject(UserService);
  data: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}


I see, the observable is responsible for comparing the attributes of my user class with the key and value objects in my json? If not, it will give an error, I mean in relation to the name of the attributes that have to be the same @Naren Murali

@vinudev Observables in your question are API calls, so they should be made with proper parameters, etc. Angular automatically converts the response to JSON, so you just need to configure the APIs to get the data, subscribe to it, and use it.

I understand, but is it the role of the observable to carry out this verification? I mean, compare the key of the json file, with the attribute of my class? @Naren Murali

@vinudev no, it simply fetches the data for what you are asking you need a webserver like node.js which runs on a port and does the DB queries and gives you the data. that is why we configure the URL in http client, so that it makes calls to this URL

I have one last question, could you tell me why, for example, I have a model with a user.ts file, why does this file have to contain the same attributes as my json file? or the attributes identical to those of my entity, if I had integrated the front-end with a back-end @Naren murali
